# adding new vertex inside 3D structure

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, 3d, vtk

I have DICOM files of a 3D structure, in order to do some changes inside my structure, I converted the 3D sructure  to stl file using ImageJ and then  store it in vtkpolydata using vtkreadstl, using the decimation algorithme I can reduce my structure by deleting some vertex and triangles, by now I want to do the reverse by adding additional vertexes, which algorithme can I use to do so?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of decimation would be either tessellation or subdivision. Tessellation is simply adding more geometry based on the algorithm you decide to use, and the point of subdivision is make a surface more smooth.

Which one you would want to use depends on what exactly your goal is with adding additional vertices.

looking at vtk, i see there is a [vtkTessellatorFilter](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkTessellatorFilter.html) and a [vtkSimpleCellTessellator](http://www.vtk.org/doc/release/5.0/html/a02009.html) which you might find helpful if you would like to tesselate your model. otherwise there are quite a few different subdivision algorithms if your goal is to get smoother surfaces by adding additional geometry. Looks like vtk has: 
[vtkLinearSubdivisionFilter](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkLinearSubdivisionFilter.html),
[vtkButterflySubdivisionFilter](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkButterflySubdivisionFilter.html),
[vtkLoopSubdivisionFilter](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkLoopSubdivisionFilter.html),
[vtkDataSetSurfaceFilter](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDataSetSurfaceFilter.html)

Comment: I tried this code but I have 0 triangles in the output, I can't find an example how to use Tessellator: `vtkTessellatorFilter tesla= new vtkTessellatorFilter();
tesla.SetInputData(input); tesla.Update();` my input is a **vtkpolydata**

Comment: @Ouznour what is your goal in adding more geometry? is it just to make the surface more smooth? or do you want do do something like adding more texture to the surface? subdivision is for making the surface more smooth, with tesselation, the goal is to implement your own algorithm, which means you have to know what exactly you are adding more geometry for, and you'd have to know how to implement an algorithm that will give you the surface you want

Comment: my goal is not just to add more geometry to the surface but also inside my 3D structure, the documentation of vtkTessellatorFilter is not very clear for me

Comment: The 3d structure is made out of triangles right? The triangles represent the surface. The smaller and more triangles you have, the more detailed the surface. So why do you want to add more geometry inside your 3d structure?

Comment: The 3d structure is a vertebra structure so the inside is much more important for me

Comment: @ouznour, my guess is that you will want to subdivide your geometry. If you need more geometry in a specific way, other than to make the surface more smooth or just adding redundant geometry, then you will have to come up with your own algorithm to add geometry specific to your application and use tesselation

Comment: Is there an algorithm for the redundant way??

Comment: yeah, you could just use one of the subdivision algorithms and set some parameter for like zero smoothing or something